# manipulate date with Jmeter

Tags: date, jmeter

I have used ${__time(dd-mm-yyyy)} function of Jmeter, i wanted to know if I can 
manipulate this function that will return me the following convention "yyyy-mm-dd", I have tried ${__time(yyyy-mm-dd)} and I have noticed that I got the following date 2015-14-25 (for today: 01-25-2015) I did not understand why I got this date convention.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it, Jmeter reference to case sensitive so in this case that would work: `${__time(yyyy-MM-dd)}`. Jmeter would reference to 'MM' as the month.